# Question about graph of sin function

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

There is question I had on my mind for 3-4 years. If you have a function:- f(x) = (sin(x))^n If you increase the value of n slowly the Value of the function at all points, except where it is one, will approach towards zero. And at a value of n around a million, the function changes to almost an impulse at odd multiples of 90° and thus seems to be non differentiable at those points(I plotted the function in MATLAB). I want to know is the function differentiable at odd multiples of 90° degrees when n is very large ( tending to infinity). If yes, how the differentiability changes as n grows. Can I get an expression of the slope of the graph having n and x as variables? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function is differentiable (infinitely often) for each $n$. Only the limit is not.

Comment: Can you explain the limit part

Comment: as you have seen in Matlab, the functions develop spikes as $n$ grows larger, at the places where $\sin(x)=1$. In the limit (taken pointwise for each $x$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$) there results a function which is identically $0$, with the exception of those points where the spikes were. At these points the limit will be equal to $1$. So you get a function which is even discontinuous as a limit. But for every given finite $n$, the function smooth, though the spikes will become more acute with increasing $n$.